# How can I solve the particular solution of the following recurrence (recursive) relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Having 
$a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3·2^{2n-1}$ 
$a_1 = 12$
$a_0 = 0$


I solved the homogeneous part and got:
$a^{{h}}_n = 1/12·2^n - 1/12·1^n$


This is the particular solution that I need to solve:

$a^{p}_n = C·3·2^{2n-1}$
but the exponent 2n-1 confuses me. I'm don't know how to solve it.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Note that $2^2=4$

Comment: @MarkBennet If I change it to $4^{n-1}$ and use 2 instead of n, I don't get the same results as with $2^{2n-1}$. Can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: $2^{2n-1}=2^{-1}\cdot 2^{2n}=\frac 12 4^n$ - the key thing is to get the exponent $n$ and absorb the other factors into the coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

We try for a particular solution of the shape $c\cdot 2^{2n-1}$. Substituting in our recurrence, we have
$$c\cdot 2^{2n-1}=3c\cdot 2^{2n-3}+2c\cdot 2^{2n-5}+3\cdot 2^{2n-1}.$$
Dividing by $2^{2n-5}$ we get
$$16c=12c+2c+48.$$

**Remark:** The algebra may feel simpler if we look for a solution of the shape $d\cdot 2^{2n}$, that is, $d\cdot 4^n$. We get $d\cdot 4^{n}=3d\cdot 4^{n-1}+2d\cdot 4^{n-2}+\frac{3}{2}\cdot 4^n$. Divide through by $4^{n-2}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear. But the solution shouldn't be $c·3·2^{2n-1}$? Taking into consideration that the non-homogeneous part is $3·2^{2n-1}$. Thanks

Comment: The constant term is plain $3\cdot 2^{2n-1}$, so that is what I have in the equation. Solve for $c$. We get $c=24$. So a particular solution is $24\cdot 2^{2n-1}$, or if you prefer $12\cdot 2^{2n}$.